# Fetching most recent related object for set of objects in Peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Suppose I have an object model A with a one-to-many relationship with B in Peewee using an sqlite backend. I want to fetch some set of A and join each with their most recent B. Is their a way to do this without looping?

```
class A(Model):
    some_field = CharField()
class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKeyField(A)
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

The naive way would be to call order_by and limit(1), but that would apply to the entire query, so

```
q = A.select().join(B).order_by(B.date.desc()).limit(1)
```

will naturally produce a singleton result, as will

```
q = B.select().order_by(B.date.desc()).limit(1).join(A)
```

I am either using prefetch wrong or it doesn't work for this, because

```
q1 = A.select()
q2 = B.select().order_by(B.date.desc()).limit(1)
q3 = prefetch(q1,q2)
len(q3[0].a_set)
len(q3[0].a_set_prefetch)
```

Neither of those sets has length 1, as desired. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize I needed to understand functions and group_by.

```
q = B.select().join(A).group_by(A).having(fn.Max(B.date)==B.date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way only if you want the latest date and not the last entry of the date. If the last date entry isn't the default one (`datetime.datetime.now`) this query will be wrong.

You can find the last date entry:

```
last_entry_date = B.select(B.date).order_by(B.id.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
```

and the related A records with this date:

with A and B fields:

```
q = A.select(A, B).join(B).where(B.date == last_entry_date)
```

with only the A fields:

```
q = B.select().join(A).where(B.date == last_entry_date)
```

If you want to find the latest B.date (as you do with the `fn.Max(B.date)`) and use it as the `where` filter:

```
latest_date = B.select(B.date).order_by(B.date.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
```